# Matlab: Issues with filling a 401x401 matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, reflection, matrix

I'm having an issue with filling a 401x401 matrix. I know exactly what I want to do but I'm struggling to implement it.

I would like for a specific angle (y axis from 30-70) and a specific wavelength (x axis from 400nm-1000nm) the matrix is filled to 401 x 401 to contain the associated reflection coefficient (I have the equations and they're all good).

I thought this would work#

```
    for i=1:length(ANGLE)
        angle=ANGLE(i);
        etc etc
        for i=1:length(wavelengths)
            lambda=wavelengths(i);
            etc etc
            REF(i)=ref;
        end
     end
```

I hope you can help, sorry if this is badly worded.
Thanks
Carmel

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you are asking. Why is it 401x401? Reflection coefficient of what? How does that relate to each index?

Comment: Maybe replace your second for loop iterator with `j` instead of `i`. Good pratice to use `ii` and `jj`.

Answer (score 0):

As m_power pointed out, you should use a different iterator for the internal for loop (and also try to avoid using i and j, as they are commonly used to represent imaginary values).  In addition to this, you should reference both a row and column entry for each reflection coefficient entry. Since you want angle in the vertical direction and wavelength in the horizontal direction, you could use something like this:

```
for ii=1:length(ANGLE)
        angle=ANGLE(ii);
        etc etc
        for jj=1:length(wavelengths)
            lambda=wavelengths(jj);
            etc etc
            REF(ii,jj)=ref;
        end
     end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In addition to this, since you know the size REF should be ahead of time, it's good practice to pre-allocate space before assigning values within a loop.  For example, you could initialize to all zeros using REF = zeros(length(ANGLE),length(wavelengths))